# Dialogflow agent isn't storing data in agent.conv().data

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

In dialogflow fulfilment the handler looks like:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  let conv = agent.conv();
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
```

I've set conv to agent.conv(). The user is welcomed and I want to store a randomly generated number.

```
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to Med Ed! Can I get your name?`);
    //generate random number -> num
    conv.data.random = num
    console.log(conv.data.random)
  }
```

The above works fine and the number is printed to the console. But when another function handler is called and I try and extract the number:

```
 function intentHandler(agent) {
        // get the number from the agent.conv()
        getNum = conv.data.random 
        console.log(getNum)
 }
```

It's print getNum is NaN to the console.

I thought data persists but I'm obviously wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using Cloud Functions either in Google Cloud Platform or from the Dialogflow inline editor.

In both cases, the fulfillment code runs in Cloud Functions which should be [stateless](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#stateless_functions). Each request could be executed in a different environment; therefore, if it's necessary to store variables, is recommended to add an additional persistance layer, for example, a database.

For your use case, there are three suggestions you can consider:

1) [Use a global variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations). Normally, the functions will be executed in the same environment, so, you could store information in a global variable; however, this is not guaranteed, so you should handle the case where that information is not available

2) [Use Dialogflow contexts as temporary storage](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-input-output#param). You can store the random number as a parameter in the context and it will be send by Dialogflow to the webhook, as long as the context is active

3) Add a persistance layer to your functions. Within GCP you could use [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) or the [database](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases/) that better fits your scenario

Comment: Thx @Tlaquetzal storing in the context works. The issue with using firestore is that it does takes time to hit the db and return. And re global vars i ran into the prob that I think the global var needs to be initialised before it's used eg. let randNum = 0. And if that is set from within a local function eg  randNum = 6, the next time fulfilment is called randNum returns to its initial value of 0.  I read this post https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/personalize-for-each-user-device-the-magic-conversation-object-def0785582f9 which is why I thought agent.conv().data could be used.

Comment: @jcantona did you try the agent.conv() approach in the "Actions on Google" platform? It is supposed to work as temporary storage there. Although, I would still go for contexts in case you want to use it for another integrations.  For global variables, in theory, the value will not be changed to the initial value unless the function is executed in a differente environment; however, since the value might not be "persisted" I'd still go for contexts

Comment: Thx. Yeah i tried using agent.conv() in actions on google but still didn't persist. But contexts work so happy with that. Thanks