# Repeat sentence in Dialogflow for VUI without external libraries (multivocal/VoiceRepeater)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to make my VUI repeat its last sentence when prompted for this (e.g. when user says 'I'm sorry, I did not hear you). I have tried to do this using the libraries multivocal and VoiceRepeater but this is not working for me so I want to implement it according to this guide: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/tips

I have already taken the following steps:

1. Created an intent called 'Repeat'.
2. Added training phrases for the intent
3. Enabled webhook call for this intent
4. In Node.js added the following code:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

function repeat(agent) {
    const REPEAT_PREFIX = [
      'Sorry, Ik zei ',
      'Laat me het herhalen: ',
      'Wat ik zei is'
    ];

      const reply = (agent, inputPrompt, noInputPrompts) => {
        agent.data.lastPrompt = inputPrompt;
        agent.data.lastNoInputPrompts = noInputPrompts;
        agent.ask(inputPrompt, noInputPrompts);
      };

    // Intent handlers
    const normalIntent = (agent) => {
      reply(agent, 'Hey this is a question', 'Ik zie niks');
    };

    let repeatPrefix = promptFetch.getRepeatPrefix(); // randomly chooses from REPEAT_PREFIX
      // Move SSML start tags over
      if (agent.data.lastPrompt.startsWith(promptFetch.getSSMLPrefix())) {
        agent.data.lastPrompt =
            agent.data.lastPrompt.slice(promptFetch.getSSMLPrefix().length);
        repeatPrefix = promptFetch.getSSMLPrefix() + repeatPrefix;
      }
      agent.add(repeatPrefix + agent.data.lastPrompt,
          agent.data.lastNoInputPrompts);  
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Repeat', repeat); 

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for me, one error I get it that it says 'FetchPrompt is not defined', which I don't understand. I know the setup is okay because this code does return: 'this is a response from the webhook' if I prompt the VUI for repeating its sentence:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

function repeat(agent) {
    agent.add('this is a response from the webhook'); 
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Repeat', repeat); 

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: In the code you send you haven't defined promptFetch, for example, ```let repeatPrefix = promptFetch.getRepeatPrefix();```. This could explain the error, but you say the code runs fine, did you add all the code to your post?

Comment: Their is code for multiple intents in my node.js but I didn't think that was relevant. Where would I define FetchPrompt? In the example in the link they don't define it either..

Comment: The code is not running fine btw, just the second piece of code, in which I have hardcoded a response

Comment: You've cited code for actions-on-google, but this is only tagged with dialogflow and showing only the dialogflow library. Are you using the actions-on-google library? Is this meant to work with Actions on Google, or with Dialogflow in general?

Comment: It is just meant to work with Dialogflow, can I include the actions-on-google library or is it 'one or the other'?

Answer (score 0):

As @Prisoner points out, your code is intended to work only with `dialogflow-fulfillment` but you based it on an actions-on-google example. That's the cause of the code errors.

Some things you want to do are only available for Actions on Google, for example, the object `conv` contains functionality that only works when executed within Google Assistant, and this is the core of the problem.

Even if you fix the code, the [example you're](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/tips) following uses `conv.data` as a temporary storage for the last reply of the agent during the conversation; however `conv.data` functionality is not availabe outside Google Assistant platforms, and, at the moment, Dialogflow doesn't have a straightforward approach to get the agent last response.

If you don't want to integrate with Google Assistant, then you'd need to find a suitable workaround to store your agent last reply. [Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60022103/7517757) where this issue with the temporary storage was discussed, maybe you can use it as a reference.

For your use case, I think you could get away with it by using contexts to store the last replies.